# Error after kernel upgrade to 3.15.1

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, fedora

I am getting below mentioned error after upgrading kernel to version 3.15.1 on every boot. I am unable to login to my machine.

**[drm:cpt_serr_int_handler] *ERROR* PCH transcoder A FIFO underrun**

My system details: 
Dell latitude e5410  corei5
OS: Fedora 20(64 bit)

Could anybody give some clue on this error and how to come out of this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not unusual for a kernel update to break something on some hardware. File a bugzilla ticket, roll back to your previous kernel, then check if the next kernel update still has this problem for you.

Comment: I had installed nVidia proprietary drivers  after upgrading kernel. After uninstalling nvidia drivers my problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found answer. Hope it would be helpful for someone.

Steps:

1. Login by disabling visual boot process by removing rhgb and quiet from kernel parameters
2. Delete installed nvidia driver by using below command
   yum remove xorg-x11-drv-nvidia*
   For more information
   http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=300024

Comment: Oh man you save my life..I didn't made like you, but almost the same way. Set  "1" after quiet parameter to boot in single user mode and then remove the bumblebee-nvidia package.